# Remove duplicates from csv and count them in Java

Tags: java, excel, csv, ip, ip-address

I'm trying to take lines of text from a log file created by my router and break it down into a csv file for ease of viewing.

an example line from the log file:

```
[VPN-IPSEC rule not match] from 192.168.1.254:63991 to 8.8.8.8:53 Wednesday, January 06,2016 08:52:18
```

I hope the end file to have a column for Rule, IP address inwards, Port Inwards, Ip Address out, port out, Host name, Date and amount of connections(duplicates).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    PrintStream diskwriter = new PrintStream("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\RawIPs.csv");

    diskwriter.print("Rule" + ",");
    diskwriter.print("Host Name" + ",");
    diskwriter.print("IP Address" + ",");
    diskwriter.println("Port");

    int count = 0;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\IPs.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    String IPaddress = line;

    String IPadd = IPaddress.substring((IPaddress.lastIndexOf("to") +3));
    String IP = IPadd.substring(0, IPadd.indexOf(":"));


    String Rule = IPaddress.substring((IPaddress.indexOf("[") +1), (IPaddress.indexOf("]")));

    String Port = IPadd.substring((IPadd.indexOf(":") +1), IPadd.indexOf(" "));

    String host;

    count++;

    if(IP.startsWith("212.56.7"))
    {
        host = "Plus Net";
    }
    else if(IP.equals("157.56.144.215") || IP.equals("40.113.152.30") || IP.equals("23.102.160.172") || IP.equals("157.56.106.184") || IP.equals("94.245.121.251") || IP.equals("157.56.75.164") || IP.equals("134.170.185.125") || IP.equals("191.237.208.126") || IP.equals("191.232.139.253") || IP.equals("157.55.231.252"))
    {
        host = "Microsoft";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("104.16.") || IP.equals("172.69.2.2"))
    {
        host = "CloudFlare";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("68.232."))
    {
        host = "EdgeCast Networks";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("192.225.15"))
    {
        host = "ThreatMetrix";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("70.32."))
    {
        host = "Gigenet";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("185.31.19"))
    {
        host = "Fastly London 1 Operations (Hosting Company)";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("96.31."))
    {
        host = "Host Collective";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("182.70."))
    {
        host = "Bharti Telenet (India - Vodafone)";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("17."))
    {
        host = "Apple Inc.";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("199.16.15"))
    {
        host = "Twitter Inc.";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("128.0."))
    {
        host = "RIPE Network Coordination Centre";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("129.1."))
    {
        host = "Bowling Green State University";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("185.42.205.144") || IP.startsWith("192.16.64.181"))
    {
        host = "Twitch.tv";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("122.248.142.74"))
    {
        host = "Netgear";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("173.241.2"))
    {
        host = "OpenX Technologies";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("69.172."))
    {
        host = "Peer 1 Network (USA)";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("204.154.110") || IP.startsWith("204.154.111"))
    {
        host = "DoubleVerify";
    }
    else if(IP.startsWith("208.146."))
    {
        host = "Internap Network Services";
    }
    else
    {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
        host = addr.getCanonicalHostName();
    }

    diskwriter.print(Rule + ",");
    diskwriter.print(host + ",");
    diskwriter.print(IP + ",");
    diskwriter.println(Port);

        }

        System.out.println("There were " + count + " connections");
    }
}
```

There are many problems I can't solve with my approach to this problem. One of those is the fact that I can't say:"If IP is greater than 192.168.1.0 and less than 192.168.1.254, host = home network" because the IP's are written as Strings to give an example.

Something I'm hoping I can get help with today specifically though is duplicates. I want to not only remove duplicates from my CSV file, but I want to count them too. whether a record counts as a duplicate or not would depend on all fields being the same not just individual records.

I would also like the amount of unique values to be saved in a variable so I can print that to the console after the loop finishes.

This can easily be done in excel using the remove duplicates function and count if's can also be done in excel, but this would require writing the formula every time or in the best case scenario, dragging formula's down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to do this perform all this logic in a single run through an IO-based while loop. Forget about CSV files and what you know about excel.  They are confusing you more than they are helping you.

Break the problem down.

Read through the log once.

Define a POJO class corresponding to each row and create a List of these objects, one per row.

POJO is "Plain Old Java Object".  Just a bunch of data fields, with setters and getters.  EG:

```
public class LogEntry {
   private String host;
   private String port; 
   private String rule;

   public String getHost() {
      return this.host;
   }

   public void setHost(String host) {
      this.host = host;
   }

   public String getPort() {
      return this.port;
   }

   public void setPort(String port) {
      this.port = port;
   }
   public String getRule() {
      return this.rule;
   }

   public void setRule(String rule) {
      this.rule = rule;
   }
}
```

Convert the IP addresses to numbers.  It's easy enough.
256^3 * first quad + 256^2 * second quad + 256 * 3rd quad + 4th quad

Run summary logic to combine the dupes, get counts etc.

Do one step at a time.  You'll get there.

Comment: Thanks for posting! As you can probably tell I'm really new to Java. and I'll have to look up some of the terminology you're using because this is the first time I've heard of the POJO class, but I appreciate your time.

Comment: POJO = "Plain Old Java Object".  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Apache's SubnetUtils would be great at this